# Mail Server on CentOS - Can the domain name and hostname be the same?

Tags: postfix, email-server, hostname, domain-name

Don't know how silly this question sounds, but can I make the mail server hostname the same as the domain name?

Example:

Typical Mailserver setup:

```
hostname: mail.example.com
domain name: example.com
```

My Mailserver Requirement

```
hostname: example.com
domain name: example.com
```

I am busy setting up Postfix for my CentOS server and I am editing the /etc/postfix/main.cf file

Thanks

Comment: This really isn't a good idea.

Comment: why do you say so?

Comment: Yes you can do so, but the question is why you want to do so? What's the reason you want to do so? I assume a reason, but I guess there would be a better solution to not run into unwanted trouble in the future.

Comment: just want to know if it is possible, since I am just testing my mail server. I don't plan on keeping it like it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but with such settings would be "**$mydomain = $myhostname = $myorigin**". In such case you should be more careful with permissions in options like mydestination

Comment: ok cool. just wanted to know if it is possible